# How to detect MetaMask login

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask

How can we detect when a user signs in to MetaMask *after* the page has loaded? Is it necessary to resort to polling, or is there an event that a page can listen out for?

Comment: You should be able to get some idea from code at https://github.com/ethereum/remix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2020, the web3 site has to ask for account access via `ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })`, and then listen for changes to the accounts via the `accountsChanged` event.

Please see [the MetaMask documentation](https://docs.metamask.io) for details.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I went with polling.  Not ideal but works well.

Answer (score 1):

Using web3 version 1.0.0, the metamask provider exposes an 'update' event you can listen to on it's publicConfigStore.

```
web3.currentProvider.publicConfigStore.on('update', callback);
```

Your callback will be passed an object with 'selectedAddress' and 'networkVersion' whenever those attributes change.

Comment: No more publicConfigStore can be found there.

Answer (score 1):

Requesting Accounts access via `'eth_requestAccounts'` is not really the best thing you can do because that will keep adding requests in metamask (bad performances) and a bad UX (popup + notifications)

the way to do it is via

```js
const isUnlocked = await window?.ethereum?._metamask.isUnlocked();
console.debug({ isUnlocked });
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check if MetaMask is connected or not without asking user for login with MetaMask

```js
if (window.ethereum._state.accounts.length > 0) {
  // metamask is already connected
  console.log(window.ethereum._state.accounts[0]);
}
```

fully working React/Next.js code:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [ismetamask, setIsmetamask] = useState(false); // is metamask installed ?
  const [accountaddress, setAccountaddress] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window) {
      // Sometimes window is not loaded, so wait
      if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
        console.log("MetaMask is installed!");
        setIsmetamask(true);

        // check if metamask is already connected
        if (window.ethereum._state.accounts.length > 0) {
          // metamask is already connected
          setAccountaddress(window.ethereum._state.accounts[0]);
        }

        // trigger when account change: logout or login
        ethereum.on("accountsChanged", function (accounts) {
        if (window.ethereum._state.accounts.length > 0) {
          setAccountaddress(window.ethereum._state.accounts[0]);
        } else {
          setAccountaddress([]);
        }
        });
      } else {
          console.log("metamask not installed");
      }
    } else {
        console.log("window not loaded yet");
    }
  }, []);

  const signinMetamask = async () => {
    // const accounts =
    await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
    // const account = accounts[0];
  };

  return (
    <>
      {ismetamask ? (
        <>
          {accountaddress.length < 1 ? (
            <>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  signinMetamask();
                }}
                className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
              >
                Connect MetaMask
              </button>
            </>
          ) : (
            <>user: {accountaddress}</>
          )}
        </>
      ) : (
        <>MetaMask not installed</>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @aakash4dev, looks interesting. I'm not working with Ethereum right now but I've tidied it up a bit in case it's useful for others. React question though - what's with all the fragments? I thought they were for use when there wasn't a single node that could obviously serve as the JSX root.